# Rails 6 + Mongoid 6.1.0 not compatible versions for gem "activemodel"

Tags: activemodel, ruby-on-rails-6, mongoid6

Trying to use Rails 6.0.0 with Mongoid 6.1.0

gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.0'
gem 'mongoid', '~> 6.1.0'

Tried already to not set the mongoid version in Gemfile, but still not working.

> Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "activemodel":
>
> > In Gemfile:
> >
> > > mongoid (~> 6.1.0) was resolved to 6.1.1, which depends on activemodel (~> 5.0
> > >
> > > rails (~> 6.0.0) was resolved to 6.0.0, which depends on activemodel (= 6.0.0)

Answer (score 9):

I´ve just found a simple way to fix this until mongoid release the latest version that is compatible

Replace the mongoid gem to:

> gem 'mongoid', git: 'https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid.git', branch: 'master'

Than

> bundle update

Comment: Still not fixed, it is Feb 2021.

I hope they do a pull.

Comment: For some reason it's still not fixed :facepalm: